# Let's $X \sim Exp(2)$ be a random variable. Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{E(X^{n})} $

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value

Probability density function of X is $f(x)=2e^{-2x}1_{(0,\infty)} (x)$. Then $E(X^{n})=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n2e^{-2x} dx =...=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\cdot n!\cdot \frac{1}{4}.$ Because of that we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{E(X^{n})} =0.$ I hope that solution is correct :)

Comment: Can you show your steps?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I calculated it using partial integration

Comment: You could simplify the analysis by observing $E[X^n]\geq 2^nP[X>2]$, which is true for any nonnegative random variable.

Comment: If you want to prove $2^n/n!\to0$, prove by induction the upper bound $(32/3)/2^n$ for $n\ge3$.

Comment: Yep, is correct, because $E(X^n)  = \Gamma(n+1)/2^n = n!/2^n$ and $1/E(X^n) = \frac{2^n}{n!} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$. You can do as suggested by J.G. or chek https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554280/show-that-lim-frac2nn-0

Comment: @daniel thanks a lot :)